# Rspec integration: param is missing or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got this Rails 4 controller like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :delete]

    # ...

    api :POST, '/users', "Creates a new user"
    param :username,    String, :required => true, :desc => "Desired username"
    param :email,       /[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\.[a-z]{2,}/, :required => true, :desc => "User's e-mail address"
    param :password,    String, :required => true, :desc => "SHA256(username:password), hex encoded"
    param :screenname,  String, :required => true, :desc => "Publicly visible name"
    param :avatar,      String, :required => true, :desc => "Uploaded avatar filename"
error :code => 422, :desc => "Unprocessable entity"
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.save
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
            else
                format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # ...

    private

    # ...

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :screenname)
    end
end
```

and then I have a rspec test like this

```
describe "POST /users.json" do
    let!(:daniel_attrs) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, username: "daniel", email: "daniel@bigbob.com", password: "999d53a384afd57ebc36986fe9455c6e941cd844467e28f975289845d6e984ee", screenname: 'Daniel', avatar: "default.png") }

    before :each do |example|
        post '/users.json', daniel_attrs
    end

# ...

end
```

which fails like this

```
1) Users API POST /users.json creates the user with the right parameters
   Failure/Error: post '/users.json', daniel_attrs
   ActionController::ParameterMissing:
     param is missing or the value is empty: user
   # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:155:in `user_params'
   # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:72:in `create'
   # ./spec/requests/usersapi_spec.rb:85:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What I'm not clear on is why would the controller even require a 'user' key in the request, since if I forge a request (via curl, postman, whatever) and I only include a json representation of my attributes, it creates the object correctly. If anyway I provide the key (as in `:user => daniel_attrs`) the test fails like this

```
1) Users API POST /users.json creates the user with the right parameters
   Failure/Error: post '/users.json', :user => daniel_attrs
   Apipie::ParamMissing:
     Missing parameter username
   # ./spec/requests/usersapi_spec.rb:85:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and I know for a fact (because I used `let!` and because I printed it out) that `daniel_attrs` has all the keys and values at the right places.

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, I haven't been at rails testing for a veeery long time. So, what is it that I'm missing?

**EDIT**: generally, it would be **massively** helpful to inspect requests before they get performed. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT 2**: Works when modifying the apipie definition like this

```
api :POST, '/users', "Creates a new user"
param :user, Hash, :required => true do
    param :username,    String, :required => true, :desc => "Desired username"
    param :email,       /[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\.[a-z]{2,}/, :required => true, :desc => "User's e-mail address"
    param :password,    String, :required => true, :desc => "SHA256(username:password), hex encoded"
    param :screenname,  String, :required => true, :desc => "Publicly visible name"
    param :avatar,      String, :required => true, :desc => "Uploaded avatar filename"
end
error :code => 422, :desc => "Unprocessable entity"
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        else
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of user_params method of your controller.

I think you can try this :

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :screenname)
end
```

Edit : Sorry I missed a part of your post, so you know the problem is because of 'user' key.
If you want to keep the user key, you can try the following syntax ( I tried it and it works )

```
post :create, user: daniel_attrs
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried both alternatives, none of them worked. Weirdly enough, and sorry for not mentioning, I had a apipie section (see edit) before the create method, which did not group the params under a :user hash. I say "weird" because the errors don't mention apipie at all.